# SAP - Java (Spring Boot) integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, sap-basis, jco

I have a Spring boot app that needs to integrate with SAP.
I researched some options, but would like to know if anyone has some experience on it and see which is the best option to can consume services from SAP.

I saw:

1. SAP Java Connector
2. Generate SOAP Web Services from SAP and consume it from my Java app

Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to SAP backend then the latter, if not then you have no other way except first.

Comment: Ok , The SAP app is in a Third party company , so I have to ask that company to facilitate some api to can integrate with other system.  I will see with them which is the best option. Thanks!